# Multidimensional array access by class with multiple variables

Tags: java

Ok, so this is a shot in the dark but...
Is there any way to overload the argument for multidimensional array access to take in custom arguments?

```
//normal array access
myArray[1][2];

//I have a class with two ints and do this
myArray[int2Var.x][int2Var.y];

//is there any way to overload the array arguments so I can do this to access a two dimensional array?
myArray[int2Var];
```

I am currently working in Java but I would also like to know if it is at all possible.

Comment: Why is it important to preserve the array-indexing syntax? This can be easily accomplished if you drop the requirement to use the syntax.

Comment: @JimGarrison it isn't, and again, thank you for your answer, and the extra note about it being [][] not [,], saved me from running into that problem just now :). When I can up-vote answers you are definitely getting one, you have been most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Java does not support operator overloading in the way C++ does.

Here's a Java version, in case you're interested:

```
public class Test {

    public static class Index
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    }
    public static <T> T get(T[][] array, Index i)
    {
        return array[i.x][i.y];
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Index ix = new Index();
        ix.x = 1;
        ix.y = 2;

        Integer[][] arr = new Integer[3][3];
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
                arr[i][j] = 3*i + j;

        System.out.println(get(arr,ix));
    }
}
```

Method `get(...)` takes an array of any reference type and an index object and returns the selected object.  For primitives you'd need one specialized `get` method per primitive type.

Note also that array syntax in java is not `[a,b]` but `[a][b]`.

Comment: So would this be possible in the C languages?

Comment: You could do this in C++, not in C.

Comment: Cool, sad I can't do it in Java, but I knew it wasn't very likely to begin with. Thank you for your quick response Jim.

Comment: I am impressed. Jim that is just amazingly done. And I learned about generic methods from it. Thank you.